# Click fails because the element is not visible

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using the following to click an element on a web page:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("SearchIcon")).Click();
```

HTML:

```
<span class="ticon ti-search ti-1x" name="SearchIcon"> </span>
```

It's suppose to be very easy and strait forward but I'm getting:

> "{"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"0","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:54912"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"","url":"/click","urlParsed":

Putting a

```
 NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Name("SearchIcon")).Enabled);
```

before the click statement passes so apparently the element is there and visible once the test runs so I don't get what's wrong here.

Comment: You probably should check that the element is [`.Displayed`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Displayed.htm) and not `.Enabled`. You probably need to wait.

Comment: No success with ext method as well..

NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Name("SearchIcon"), 10).Displayed);
                         
public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
                return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
            }
            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
    }

Comment: check the "set window size" workaround here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585 it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit old but I stumbled across it. It may help others.

You could create an extension method that checks if an element exists:

```
    public static bool Exists(this IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            var text = element.Text;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You could then Assert like:

```
var searchIcon = driver.FindElement(By.Name("SearchIcon"));

NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(searchIcon.Exists());
```